# CD Drive Error - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have just installed Ubuntu on my mom's three year old HP system. I am having an issue with the cd drive. I have two: CD and DVDR/CDR.

1. Only one drive is showing on the computer
2. When I put a CD into the drive, it spins and acts like it's doing something - yet doesn't ever show up on the system.
3. When I click on the one CD Drive that is showing, it doesn't open up the CD Drive window to view its contents. It's like I'm clicking a dead link or something.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this? Once I get this fixed I can then try to figure out how to burn a cd which I'm sure will be a nightmare.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the use of ACPI routing information during the PCI configuration:

- Press F6 at the boot menu
- Add this to the end of the line

```
pci=noacpi
```

- boot up

Comment: I assume LiveCD = when I boot Ubuntu from a live disc? If so, I have Ubuntu already installed on the computer.

Comment: It should work for both

Answer (score 0):

The CD Drive is probably toast. I've had drives fail in a couple of ways. Since the DVDR/CDR drive has a superset of features, you might be able to just use that.

Try `ls /dev/cd*` to see what you find. I find cdrom1 and cdrw1 for my same drive--you should see cdrom2 at least.

Try `eject` and then `eject -t` on the devices. All that does is open and close the tray.